# Resulting biased distribution when conditionally choosing a RV from uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability

I was reading a paper by Degorre et al. (https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.72.062314). They present the following protocol, where $\it U_\Lambda$ stands for the uniform distribution on the set $\Lambda$ and $\vec a$ is an arbitrary vector from $\mathbb{R^2}$ (can also be restricted to the unit sphere $S_2$):

1. Alice picks $\vec \lambda_1$ from $\it U_{S_{2}}$
2. Alice picks $\vec \lambda_2$ from $\it U_{S_{2}}$
3. Alice then sets $\vec \lambda_s =
   \begin{cases}
   \vec \lambda_1, & \text{if } \lvert \vec a \cdot \vec \lambda_1 \rvert \ge \lvert \vec a \cdot \vec \lambda_2 \rvert\\
   \vec \lambda_2, & \text{else}
   \end{cases}
   $

They claim that the resulting density of $\vec \lambda_s$ is $\rho(\vec \lambda_s \vert \vec a)=\lvert \vec a \cdot \vec \lambda_s \rvert / 2\pi$.

I do not understand their proof at all and was not able to find one myself because I cannot wrap my head around what integrals I have to evaluate.

I felt that the integral over the cap of the sphere
$$\int_{\lvert \vec a \cdot \vec \lambda \rvert \ge \lvert \vec a \cdot \vec \lambda_0 \rvert\\}{d\vec\lambda} = 4\pi [1-\cos(\angle\vec a,\vec \lambda_0)] = 4\pi (1-\vec a \cdot \vec \lambda_0)$$
with $\vec a \in S_2$ and $\vec \lambda_0$ from $\mathcal{U}_{S_2}$ was closely related to the problem, but I could not make it work.

It would be a great help to me if you could help me find the relevant integrals that I need to evaluate to get the resulting distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a full answer, but since you asked which integrals to evaluate:

Conditionally on $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ we have

$$ \lambda_s \vert \lambda_1,\lambda_2 = \mathbb{I}\left[\vert \lambda_1^T a \vert \geq \vert \lambda_2^Ta \vert \right] \lambda_1 + (1-\mathbb{I}\left[\vert \lambda_1^T a \vert \geq \vert \lambda_2^Ta \vert \right]) \lambda_2$$
where $\mathbb{I}[\cdots]$ is the indicator function.

Thus, let us write the conditional density suggestively as

$$p(\lambda_s \vert \lambda_1,\lambda_2) = \mathbb{I}\left[\vert \lambda_1^T a \vert \geq \vert \lambda_2^Ta \vert \right] \delta_{\lambda_1}(\lambda_s) + (1-\mathbb{I}\left[\vert \lambda_1^T a \vert \geq \vert \lambda_2^Ta \vert \right]) \delta_{\lambda_2}(\lambda_s).$$

Now since the $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are indepedent, uniformly distributed on the unit sphere, the joint probability is just the conditional times $\frac{1}{4\pi^2}$.

To get the marginal probability $p(\lambda_s)$, we now have to evaluate

$$\int \int p(\lambda_s,\lambda_1,\lambda_2) d\lambda_1 d\lambda_2 \propto \int \int \mathbb{I}\left[\vert \lambda_1^T a \vert \geq \vert \lambda_2^Ta \vert \right] \delta_{\lambda_1}(\lambda_s) + (1-\mathbb{I}\left[\vert \lambda_1^T a \vert \geq \vert \lambda_2^Ta \vert \right]) \delta_{\lambda_2}(\lambda_s) d\lambda_1 d\lambda_2  = \\ \int \int  \mathbb{I}\left[\vert \lambda_1^T a \vert \geq \vert \lambda_2^Ta \vert \right] \delta_{\lambda_s}(\lambda_1) d \lambda_1 d\lambda_2+  \int \int (1-\mathbb{I}\left[\vert \lambda_1^T a \vert \geq \vert \lambda_2^Ta \vert \right]) \delta_{\lambda_s}(\lambda_2) d\lambda_2 d\lambda_1 \\
= \int_{\vert \lambda_s^T a \vert \geq \vert \lambda_2^Ta \vert} d \lambda_2 + \int_{\vert \lambda_s^T a \vert \geq \vert \lambda_1^Ta \vert} d \lambda_1 \\ = 2 \int_{\vert \lambda_s^T a \vert \geq \vert \lambda^Ta \vert} d \lambda $$

(I suppose there is a more elegant way to get the solution directly, also you should note the radial symmetry in $a$).

Comment: Why is the factor $\frac{1}{4\pi^2}$ and not $\frac{1}{4\pi}$?
Can we combine the integrals because both $\lambda$ have the same distribution?

Comment: If the two variables are independent, then $p(\lambda_1,\lambda_2) = p(\lambda_1)p(\lambda_2)$, so it should be squared. The last step with the integrals is just renaming the variables basically.

Answer (score 0):

To help you visualise what is happening, you are looking at the curved surface area of the grey [caps of this sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) or rather at their complement of the pink surface area.

That will give you something proportional to a conditional probability for each point of another randomly selected point being in a sense further from $\mathbf a$, and this can be turned in a density by ensuring that its integral over the whole sphere is $1$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the visualisation of the integral. The surface area of the complement is directly proportional to the desired density.

However, I do not know, how to obtain the desired distribution from this result.

Comment: The density at $\lambda_0$ is proportional to that area (because that is proportional to the likelihood of setting $\lambda_s=\lambda_0$), so you integrate it over $\lambda_0$ on the whole sphere and that gives you an number to divide that area by so you have a density which would integrate across the sphere to $1$.